# How do I change the quotes on xml Declaration using Java File Handling?

Tags: java, xml, file-handling

I currently have a bunch of XML files and the task was to change the text under a specific element. So, in my logic, I was fetching the root element, getting its children and then for the specific children element, I was using `setText()` method to change the content of it.
Now the only issue is, the XML declaration which initially was:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

changes to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I tried creating a string buffer and replacing the line, but for some reason it's not working. The code for it was as follows:

```java
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    buffer.append(sc.nextLine()+System.lineSeparator());
}
String fileContents = buffer.toString();
sc.close();
String oldLine = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
String newLine = "<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>";
try {
    fileContents = fileContents.replaceAll(oldLine, newLine);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Not Changed");
}
```

Does anyone know an approach that could work for this scenario?

Comment: Your code never writes the changed text back to the file. Moreover, you probably need to trim your lines, otherwise your comparison may fail due to whitespace/non-printing chars. That said, you are already reading the file line by line. Why do you concatenate all that lines, if you need to replace a complete line anyways? Keep the lines separate and write them back to the file line by (changed) line. That's what [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) is for.

Comment: And ... seriously ... an XML parser doesn't care if you use single or double quotes in the XML declaration.  They *mean* the same thing.  So why are you even doing this?

Comment: *"... your comparison may fail due to whitespace/non-printing chars ... "* - That includes embedded whitespace, so trimming may not be sufficient.  And there are numerous other edge-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Method `replaceAll` treats its first argument as a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

The question mark (i.e. `?`) is a [metacharacter](https://www.regextutorial.org/regular-expression-metacharacters.php) but you want to treat it as a normal character.

You have two options:

1. Call method [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) rather than method `replaceAll`.
2. Escape the question marks by preceding them with a [double] backslash (i.e. `\`)

```java
String oldLine = "<\\?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"\\?>";
String newLine = "<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>";
fileContents = fileContents.replaceAll(oldLine, newLine);
```